# Any resources for this SQL filtering?

Tags: sql, filter, group-by, bigdata

I have 100 tables each of size of order of few tenths of GB. The schema of each table is the following:

A: string | B: string | C: string

In each table I would like to retain only the rows for which the (B, C) appears at least 10 times in a concatenation of all 100 tables. Is there any efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: What determines the order to concatenate the values across the 100 tables? Do you mean were B+C from table 1 matches B+C from any other table at least ten times?

Comment: Yes, for example there is a row “Hobby, Book, XYZ” in Table 1. If “Book, XYZ” appears in any Table including Table 1 in 2nd and 3rd column (first column value is unimportant) at least 10 times, I want to retain all those rows in all tables which has these values.

Comment: If you have only few combinations of `B+C`, then have a look at this article where Paul White describes a [Recursive Index Skip Scan](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/performance-tuning-whole-plan) method to find distinct values in a large table without performing a full index scan, but doing index seeks recursively.

Comment: Looks like the common question about how to get the bestselling items from all products sold in the last 12 months where sales data in broken out in a different table for each month.

Same for rolling error log tables, rolling payroll tables, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very vague question, excluding your DBMS as well isn't helpful as SQL comes in different forms.

But first, you would have to join all of the tables together - there may be a faster way of doing this, but without knowing which flavor of SQL you are using it is hard to tell.

Something like this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table_2
...
UNION 
SELECT * FROM table_100
```

Once you have all of the data you do something like this:

```
WITH tables_with_counts as (SELECT
A,
B,
C,
COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY(B, C)) AS bc_count
FROM
aggragated_tables)

SELECT
A,
B,
C
FROM 
tables_with_counts
WHERE
bc_count >= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take:

Step 1 : Aggregate all tables into one. It would be bulky but if you are using Oracle database, I think it shouldn't be an issue.

Step 2: Create md5 checksum hash values for B,C columns like below :

SELECT APEX_ITEM.MD5_CHECKSUM(B,C) md5_cks,
A,B,C
FROM aggregated_tables

Step 3: take count based on checksum values and retain the rows where count > 10

Step 4: Get rid of duplicate data using rank() or dense rank() in delete statement.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer, which I'm sure that you don't want to hear, is "no."  In the context of relational databases there is no efficient query to merge 100 tables.

It is not all bad news though.  If it were just one table (let's say it was named "combined" just to have concrete examples) you could use an elegant SQL using windowed functions

```
select A,B,C from (select A,B,C,count(1) over (partition by B,C) as counts from combined)counted where counts>=10
```

**Option 1.** So the question is how to get a "combined" table so that the snippet above works. If we stick with ANSI (standard) sql, you could use UNION ALL, which and collect it into a WITH clause to keep things neat.
Here is an example:

```
with 
  combined as (
    select * from table_1
    union all 
    select * from table_2),
  counted as (
    select 
      A,B,C,
      count(1) over (partition by B,C) as counts 
    from 
      combined)
select A,B,C from counted where counts>=10;
```

I only included 2 tables, but the real query would extend that up to table_100. Thats a lot of typing and not very efficient with the programmer's time. Also unions and union all's  are notoriously poor performing for databases, so this is not efficient in terms of system resources or time, either.  Personally I would not do it this way, but it is an answer.

**Option 2** There are other options which do not exactly match your question, but may be helpful to know. Any time you are tempted to create multiple tables with exactly the same schema, you will be better off creating a single table with multiple partitions. see [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-list.html), [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html), [Sql Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16), [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-7221F7EC-4AFB-412F-8A4F-766CBE24CAE0.htm), [Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+ddl#LanguageManualDDL-PartitionedTables).  Every database platform has its own syntax for partitioning tables but they are all similar. For this table, each of the original tables becomes a single partition in the table, and the table name would be a really good candidate for the string value in the partition identifier (partition column)

If you are able to stuff all of your 100 tables into 100 partitions of one table then you can run the first query after all.  The advantage is that the database can optimize that query because all modern databases are optimized to manage partitioned queries.

In addition, adding a partition to a table is really no more trouble than creating a new table instead, but supporting and maintaining one table is a lot less trouble than 100 tables.

**A third option**, since you tagged "big data" is to use a big data engine like Spark with SparkSQL. This would be objectively best because you can actually load a dataframe with 100 combined tables very efficiently with spark, and the SQL after that is not much different from the relational database sql we have been considering. That's kind of out of scope here, but worth considering. If you submit a more specific question and specifically for spark we could go into more details.